How to prove that gradient vector is always perpendicular to the level curve when the function is a single variable function
When we have a single variable function, let's say it's $y=x^2$. Then find its gradient vector, which should be $2x$, but how is this gradient vector represented? Does it mean its $i$ component or $j$ component is $2x$?
Then, we derive the level curve of the function $y=x^2$, this is equivalent to let $x^2=k$, where $k$ is a constant.

When x=1, the gradient "vector" is 2, so how can I relate it back to prove that at point $(1,1)$, the gradient vector here is always perpendicular to the level curve $x^2=k$

First, let's understand what truly is a level set. If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, then the level set at the level $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is the manifold given by the equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = c$. Notice that this set lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$, as does the gradien $\nabla f = (\partial_1f, \dots, \partial_nf)$.
Now, if the function is $f(x) = x^2$, then the level set at level $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is indeed given by $x^2 = c$, which means that it is the set $\{-\sqrt{c}, \sqrt{c}\}$. Notice that the gradient is in fact $2x$ and so the gradient at $\pm\sqrt{c}$ is $\pm 2\sqrt{c}$. Graphically, this can be seen:

(which is as perpendicular as a point and a vector can be in one dimension).
Now, if you want your level set to be something like $y = x^2$, then the function you want is actually $f(x,y) = y - x^2$ at level $c = 0$. Then your level set is the standard parabola and the gradient at a point $(x, x^2)$ is $(-2x, 1)$, which will be perpendicular to the level set. Note that "perpendicular" here is something odd to define, since the level set is not itself a vector or even a straight line.
Saying that the gradient is perpendicular to the level set means that the gradient is perpendicular to the tangent line to the level set at the point (talking about lines here because $y = x^2$ is one-dimensional). More generally, if $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = c$ is your level set, then you can compute the tangent space of this level set at the point $p = (p_1, \dots, p_n)$ by the equation (in variable $x$) \begin{equation}\nabla f \cdot (x - p) = 0.\end{equation} Notice that the gradient will be perpendicular by definition of the tangent space.

Great answer! Thanks! But when you change $f(x)$ to $f(x,y)$, the function is changed from one variable to two variables. Is it because we don't have the concept of vector to one point?

What do you mean by "vector to one point"?

I mean at the point $-\sqrt{c}$ and $\sqrt{c}$, the gradient is $-2\sqrt{c}$ and $+2\sqrt{c}$. But how can a vector form like you have drawn out? Is there something that defines how two points are perpendicular to one another?
That's how can we use the idea of "gradient vector" is always perpendicular to the tangent line to illustrate in this question without changing $f(x)$to $f(x,y)$

You are making a confusion here: a point and a vector do in fact have the same look, at least algebraically, but we think of them as behaving differently in the geometric sense. I represent $\sqrt{c}$ as a point, because it is an element of the level set, but I represent $2\sqrt{c}$ as a vector because it is the gradient. Notice that it has double the magnitude of $\sqrt{c}$ and is pointing right because $2\sqrt{c}$ is positive.

Thanks! Understand now. But want to clarify one more thing. That's the gradient (vector) for a single variable function is a vector with only  $x$-components right? This means that its gradient will always lie on the $x$-axis. And since under this circumstance, our level set is a set of points on $x$-axis.
But what should we treat the points in the level sets to be? If they are vectors, since gradient and "points" both lie on $x$-axis. How can they be perpendicular to each other?

Now, for the perpendicularity, it gets tricky in one-dimension: the easiest thing to do is to find the tangent linear space to the point $p$, which is given by $\nabla f \cdot x = 0$ (notice that if the point is $p \neq 0$ then this equation defines an affine space not really tangent to the level set, since it doesn't passes through $p$, but we give up the geometry here to make the space actually linear, that is, passing through $0$). For $f(x) = x^2$, this is given at $p = \sqrt{c}$ by $2\sqrt{c} x = 0$, that is, $x = 0$. Then the gradient is perpendicular since $2\sqrt{c} \cdot 0 = 0$.

Notice that here I just used the linear-algebraic version of perpendicularity: $v$ is perpendicular to the subspace $W$ if $v \cdot u = 0$ for all $u \in W$. Since in this case $v = 2\sqrt{c}$ and $W = {0}$, perpendicularity follows.

Why is the space $W={0}$? Thanks

Because the space is defined by the equation $\nabla f \cdot x = 0$, that is, $2\sqrt{c} x = 0$, hence $x = 0$ is the only point in the space (I made two separate comments for the perpendicularity part, maybe you missed the first one).

Thanks! So, here we try to find the tangent linear space instead of the tangent line because perpendicularity will get tricky in one-dimension. If it is above one-dimension and below three dimensions, then finding the tangent line geometrically will be okay right? But the the dimensions get higher, we still need to go back and resort to the tangent linear space? Thanks!
